# VLC media player how to freeze the window size?

Tags: vlc-media-player

does someone know a solution to this VLC issue:

the size of VLC program's window is changing whenever the playlist switches to another media file. Any way to freeze the current size of the window and only allow manual resizing?  This is annoying especially when running a split screen and vlc keeps resizing for every new clip.

Answer (score 1):

From [stop-vlc-media-player-from-automatically-resizing](https://windowsloop.com/stop-vlc-media-player-from-automatically-resizing/)

In the preferences window, make sure that the "Simple" mode is selected under the "Show Settings" section. Next, uncheck the "Resize interface to video size" option. Click on the "Save" button to save the changes.